# How to count authenticated and anonymous users currently online?

Tags: plone, zope

I just found the query online. I want to figure out the way.

**Only an enthusiast would like to solve this(caution)**

I would like to know how many anonymous users are online.
The server has no a priori notion which users are "online".
You may artificially define the term "session" and then consider the number of session as representing the number of online users.
If you do this and you use Zope sessions to implement your notion of "session", then you can look at the "session_data_manager" to find out how many sessions are available.
This would be more than enough to me, to know how many sessions are still available. If I could have the list of the ids of every active session, I could 
easily build the list I need (by the getSessionDataByKey() method)...
I tried with  something like :

but not even "manager" is allowed to execute that.

Even trying an External Method :

```
def activesessionlist( self):
    return self.temp_folder.keys()
```

does not have any effect, instead :

```
def sessionperiod( self):
    return self.temp_folder.getPeriodSeconds()
```

works right.

Could you please help me find out the list of active sessions? this is 
driving me crazy...

[Reference](https://mail.zope.org/pipermail/zope/2006-March/165604.html)

Comment: Have you considered instead doing some instrumenting of your analytics?

Comment: Yes but i have a fair level of zope and plone. So, thought to sought help.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like check check how many anonymous users are online, you have to create a session for each user whether its anonymous or authenticated. Once you have created the session. after that you can calculate the number of online user using "session_data_manager"

```
def activesessionlist(self):
  # GET Session Data Manager Object
  sdm = self.context.session_data_manager
  # Create Session if it's not created
  session = sdm.getSessionData(create=True)
  # Get Container where all the session object is stroed
  container = sdm._getSessionDataContainer()
  # Get Total Count of Active Session
  active_users = len(container.keys())
  return active_users
```

Comment: One note: creating a session for every anonymous user can lead to performance issue and conflicts on the temporary storage.